# problem to understand content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

dear i am confused the use of content provider in android applications.i go through various sides and read it but i am still confused about content provider ..can any one explain it in some simple way ,how to use it?

Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications....whats that means?

can it means any package name or in same pakage name...
if  i am making another app of diffrent package name then that c.p. is available also in that package?

Comment: Also format your questions to be clearer, you will get more answers (avoid pls pls, avoid multiple question marks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to use it?

you actually don't use it directly, but via the content resolver (which will, according to the URI you give it, query the right ContentProvider) :

```
getContentResolver().query("content://com.myapp.myprovider/data/", ...);
```

will find your content provider if that one is registered to handle URIs that match "content://com.myapp.myprovider/data/"

> if i am making another app of diffrent
>   package name then that c.p. is
>   available also in that package?

If you decide to publish the content provider, it is available outside of your application (this is a setting in the manifest).

> what is the major benifit of using c.p.?

It is a common design pattern in Android to offer access to data. Major benefit is that you can abstract access to your data and decide whether to open it to other applications or not. For instance, without content providers, you could not access the media stored on the phone or the contacts of the phone.

Answer (score 4):

OK, first of all, a content provider will be used if and only if you want to use the same data through several applications. You can still use it if you want to implement it in your application.
Now, by definition a ContentProvider "Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data security." (According to Android Developer Guides)

So in other words, it's like a new layer of abstraction that you are adding to your data, assigning a new man-in-the-middle that will request everything you ask it to do (read, write, update your database, files, or webservices). And this man-in-the-middle is not only available for you, it's also available for other apps if you set the tag `android:exported` to true in the `<provider>` in your manifest file.

A ContentProvider needs you to implement:

1. A contract: Basically a class with public static variables with your tables names and the fields of info for those tables.
2. A data model: Normally a database in SQLite but you can implement it also with third party libraries like SugarORM, GreenDao, Retrofit, local files, etc).
3. Your custom ContentProvider: Extend ContentProvider and inside here set the calls to your data model.

This is a good tutorial on how to make your own ContentProvider:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/

There are also a few libraries that will help you create a ContentProvider automatically (I find it amazing because it takes you like 10 min to set up everything, instead of creating your own ContentProvider from scratch which could take you days).
My personal favorite is Schematic:
https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic

I hope it helps. Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Since a package is meant as a unique identifier for an application, how can you create an app with the same package name? If this was your question, I think I've answered it. If you don't understand something else - feel free to ask. Good luck!

P.S. Consider accepting some answers, your accept ratio is low.